# How do I use a JButton in more than 1 method?

Tags: java, inheritance, jbutton

So I've been coding my TicTacToe project as a side project for some time now, and have hit another obstacle. I want to use a JButton in more than one method, but I don't know how to go about doing that. Here's my code till now.

`

```
import java.util.Random ;
import java.util.Scanner ;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane ;
import javax.swing.JFrame ;
import javax.swing.JPanel ;
import java.util.InputMismatchException ;
import java.awt.BorderLayout ;
import java.awt.* ;
import java.awt.event.* ;
import javax.swing.JTextArea ;
import javax.swing.JButton ;
import javax.swing.JRadioButton ;

class TicTacToe 
 {
    public int count = 1 ; 
    public String letter;
    public boolean b1bool = true ;
    public boolean b2bool = true ;
    public boolean b3bool = true ;
    public boolean b4bool = true ;
    public boolean b5bool = true ;
    public boolean b6bool = true ;
    public boolean b7bool = true ;
    public boolean b8bool = true ;
    public boolean b9bool = true ;
     public boolean win = false ;


    public void main(String []args) 
    {

        popupintroscreen();

    }
    public void popupintroscreen()
    {

        JTextArea introtext = new JTextArea("Welcome to TicTacToe v1.0. This is a Simple Tic Tac Toe app coded  by Abhishek Pisharody. Press the button below to play, or view the        instructions first, if you prefer. We hope you enjoy playing. Thank you.");
        introtext.setEditable(false);
        introtext.setLineWrap(true);

        JButton startgamebutton = new JButton("Start Game");
        startgamebutton.setToolTipText("Start a game of Tic-Tac-Toe");
        startgamebutton.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
        {
           @Override
           public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent gamestart)
           {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Loading.....done!");
            tictactoe();
           }
        });

        JButton showinstructions = new JButton("Show Instructions");
        showinstructions.setToolTipText("View game instructions. Worth checking out even if you know how to play.");
        showinstructions.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent displayinstructionsprompt)
            {
              JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Nothing to see here..yet..off you go!");  
            }
        });

        JButton highscoresbutton = new JButton("High Scores");
        highscoresbutton.setToolTipText("Show high scores for the game");
        highscoresbutton.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent highscoresbuttonclicked)
            {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Not coded yet!");
            }
        });

        JButton quitgamebutton = new JButton("Quit Game");
        quitgamebutton.setToolTipText("Quit the game. But why? :(");
        quitgamebutton.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent onquitgamebuttonclick)
            {
                JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, "Really quit?");
                System.exit(0);
            }
        });


        JPanel gamebuttonsholder = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
        gamebuttonsholder.setSize(400,100);
        gamebuttonsholder.add(introtext,BorderLayout.PAGE_START);
        gamebuttonsholder.add(startgamebutton,BorderLayout.PAGE_END);
        gamebuttonsholder.add(showinstructions,BorderLayout.LINE_START);
        gamebuttonsholder.add(highscoresbutton,BorderLayout.CENTER);
        gamebuttonsholder.add(quitgamebutton,BorderLayout.LINE_END);


        JFrame introscreen = new JFrame("Tic Tac Toe");
        introscreen.setSize(400,400);
        introscreen.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        introscreen.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        introscreen.add(gamebuttonsholder);
        introscreen.setVisible(true);
    }

        public int tictactoe()
        {

            final JButton b1 = new JButton("");
            b1.setToolTipText("Mark this box");
            b1.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
            {
                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent onclickb1)
                {
                   if (b1bool == true){ count++;
                    if(count == 1||count == 3 || count == 5 || count == 7 || count == 9 || count == 11)
                    {
                      letter = "O" ;

                }
                else if ( count == 2 || count == 4 || count == 6 || count == 8 || count == 10)
                {
                    letter = "X" ;                  

                }
                b1.setText(letter);
                b1bool = false ;
                calculatevictory();
                processturn();

            }}});

            final JButton b2 = new JButton("");
            b2.setToolTipText("Mark this box");
            b2.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
            {
                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent onclickb1)
                {
                   if (b2bool == true){ count++;
                    if(count == 1||count == 3 || count == 5 || count == 7 || count == 9 || count == 11)
                    {
                      letter = "O" ;

                }
                else if ( count == 2 || count == 4 || count == 6 || count == 8 || count == 10)
                {
                    letter = "X" ;                  

                }
                b2.setText(letter);
                b2bool = false ;
                calculatevictory();
                processturn();
            }}
                });


            final JButton b3 = new JButton("");
            b3.setToolTipText("Mark this box");
            b3.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
            {
                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent onclickb1)
                {
                     if(b3bool == true){
                         count++;
                    if(count == 1||count == 3 || count == 5 || count == 7 || count == 9 || count == 11)
                    {
                      letter = "O" ;

                }
                else if ( count == 2 || count == 4 || count == 6 || count == 8 || count == 10)
                {
                    letter = "X" ;                  

                }
                b3.setText(letter);
                b3bool = false ;
                calculatevictory();
                processturn();
            }}

            });

            final JButton b4 = new JButton("");
            b4.setToolTipText("Mark this box");
            b4.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
            {
                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent onclickb1)
                {
                    if(b4bool == true){

                    count++;
                        if(count == 1||count == 3 || count == 5 || count == 7 || count == 9 || count == 11)
                    {
                      letter = "O" ;

                }
                else if ( count == 2 || count == 4 || count == 6 || count == 8 || count == 10)
                {
                    letter = "X" ;                  

                }
                    b4.setText(letter);
                    b4bool = false ;
                    calculatevictory();
                    processturn();
                }}
            });

            final JButton b5 = new JButton("");
            b5.setToolTipText("Mark this box");
            b5.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
            {
                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent onclickb1)
                {
                    if (b5bool == true){
                        count++;
                        if(count == 1||count == 3 || count == 5 || count == 7 || count == 9 || count == 11)
                    {
                      letter = "O" ;

                }
                else if ( count == 2 || count == 4 || count == 6 || count == 8 || count == 10)
                {
                    letter = "X" ;                  

                }
                    b5.setText(letter);
                    b5bool = false ;
                    calculatevictory();
                    processturn();
                }}
            });

            final JButton b6 = new JButton("");
            b6.setToolTipText("Mark this box");
            b6.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
            {
                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent onclickb1)
                {
                    if (b6bool == true){
                        count++;
                        if(count == 1||count == 3 || count == 5 || count == 7 || count == 9 || count == 11)
                    {
                      letter = "O" ;

                }
                else if ( count == 2 || count == 4 || count == 6 || count == 8 || count == 10)
                {
                    letter = "X" ;                  

                }
                    b6.setText(letter);
                    b6bool = false ;
                    calculatevictory();
                    processturn();
                }}
            });

            final JButton b7 = new JButton("");
            b7.setToolTipText("Mark this box");
            b7.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
            {
                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent onclickb1)
                {
                    if (b7bool == true){
                        count++;
                        if(count == 1||count == 3 || count == 5 || count == 7 || count == 9 || count == 11)
                    {
                      letter = "O" ;

                }
                else if ( count == 2 || count == 4 || count == 6 || count == 8 || count == 10)
                {
                    letter = "X" ;                  

                }
                    b7.setText(letter);
                    b7bool = false ;
                    calculatevictory();
                    processturn();
                }}
            });

            final JButton b8 = new JButton("");
            b8.setToolTipText("Mark this box");
            b8.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
            {
                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent onclickb1)
                {
                    if(b8bool == true){
                        count++;
                        if(count == 1||count == 3 || count == 5 || count == 7 || count == 9 || count == 11)
                    {
                      letter = "O" ;

                }
                else if ( count == 2 || count == 4 || count == 6 || count == 8 || count == 10)
                {
                    letter = "X" ;                  

                }
                    b8.setText(letter);
                    b8bool = false ;
                    calculatevictory();
                    processturn();
                }}
            });

            final JButton b9 = new JButton("");
            b9.setToolTipText("Mark this box");
            b9.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
            {
                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent onclickb1)
                {
                   if(b9bool == true){
                       count++;
                        if(count == 1||count == 3 || count == 5 || count == 7 || count == 9 || count == 11)
                    {
                      letter = "O" ;

                }
                else if ( count == 2 || count == 4 || count == 6 || count == 8 || count == 10)
                {
                    letter = "X" ;                  

                }
                    b9.setText(letter);
                    b9bool = false ;
                    calculatevictory();
                    processturn();
                }}
            });

            GridLayout gamescreenlayout = new GridLayout(3,3);

            JPanel gamescreencontent = new JPanel();
            gamescreencontent.setLayout(gamescreenlayout);
            gamescreencontent.setSize(400,400);
            gamescreencontent.add(b1);
            gamescreencontent.add(b2);
            gamescreencontent.add(b3);
            gamescreencontent.add(b4);
            gamescreencontent.add(b5);
            gamescreencontent.add(b5);
            gamescreencontent.add(b6);
            gamescreencontent.add(b7);
            gamescreencontent.add(b8);
            gamescreencontent.add(b9);



            JFrame gamescreen = new JFrame("Tic-Tac-Toe");
            gamescreen.setSize(400,400) ;
            gamescreen.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
            gamescreen.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
            gamescreen.add(gamescreencontent);
            gamescreen.setVisible(true);

            int sexyshit = 1 ;
            return sexyshit ;
        }

        public void calculatevictory(){
            if (b1.getText() == b2.getText() && b2.getText() == b3.getText() && b1.getText() != "")
            {
                win = true ;
            }
            else if (b4.getText() == b5.getText() && b5.getText() == b6.getText() && b4.getText() != "")
            {
                win = true ;
            }
            else if (b7.getText() == b8.getText() && b8.getText() == b9.getText() && b7.getText() != "")
            {
                win = true ;
            }
            else if (b1.getText() == b4.getText() && b4.getText() == b7.getText() && b1.getText() != "")
            {
                win = true ;
            }
            else if (b2.getText() == b5.getText() && b5.getText() == b8.getText() && b2.getText() != "")
            {
                win = true ;
            }
            else if (b3.getText() == b6.getText() && b6.getText() == b9.getText() && b3.getText() != "")
            {
                win = true ;
            }
            else if (b1.getText() == b5.getText() && b5.getText() == b9.getText() && b1.getText() != "")
            {
                win = true ;
            }
            else if (b3.getText() == b5.getText() && b5.getText() == b7.getText() && b3.getText() != "")
            {
                win = true ;
            }
            else 
            {
                win = false ;
            }
        }




            public void processturn()
            {
            if (win == true)
            {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, letter + "wins!");
            }
            else if ( count == 9 && win == false)
            {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Tie Game");
            }
        }














    }`
```

When I try to run this, it tells me that the compiler couldn't find symbol b1. Would I have to make the buttons public(if so, how?), or use Inheritance? If it's the latter, please explain in simple terms, because I really haven't begun to learn inheritance yet.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: make it as a instance member.

Comment: Instead of dumping code please elaborate on what you mean by `in more than one method`, is it the same button or different buttons. Would the use of the button differ and if so how? etc.

Comment: @Suresh Thanks for the answer. How do I go about doing that, exactly?

Comment: @Thomas , I added some more information, and am currently adding more via an edit.

Comment: @RoboticMoneylender `private JButton buttonYouNeed;` I bet you've seen that. That's a class member.

Comment: @RoboticMoneylender you already have instance members like `count` and `win`. If you don't know how to make a button an instance member, you should start with the basics first before jumping into ui programming with all its little pitfalls.

Comment: @HugoSousa , so I declare all my JButtons and set them to private before starting my main method?

Comment: Btw, your `main()` isn't static and thus is no real main method.

Comment: @RoboticMoneylender Not sure what you want to do. If you're coding a listener, you don't need to have them as instance members, there's methods to access the clicked button. If you actually need them, you should have a list of `JButton` or some kind of object to store them, yes.

Comment: @Thomas , ah, thanks for the explanation. I didn't exactly know the technical term for variables declared before calling the method. I only knew that I could call them anywhere in the class. I am currently learning the basics, this little project of mine was just my feeble attempt at getting my feet wet in GUI Programming. I didn't set main as static so as to be able to use ActionListener without having to use the implements statement, as I'm still reading up on that. So my main method has to be static in order for the compiler to recognize it as main?

Comment: @RoboticMoneylender have a look at the tutorials for some more information on class members and terminology, e.g. [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/index.html). Additionally I'd advise you to get started with some command line programming to get the basics before "going big" with ui and such. This will save you a few headaches.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Declare your `JButton` outside the method, in the same place as where you are declaring your `int`, `String`, and `boolean`s. In other words, something like

```
class TicTacToe
{
    //...
    JButton b1;
    //...
    public int TicTacToe()
    {
        b1 = new JButton(); //note that you don't need the ""
    }
}
```

Incidentally, I'd recommend using arrays and looping through them rather than having 9 of everything and having to copy-paste code lots of times.

Comment: I try, but get this error: local variable b1 is accessed from inner class ; needs to be declared final.

Comment: @RoboticMoneylender Do what it says, declare it as `final`. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10259547/java-final-variables